# Why not include another assumption within this natural deduction proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Question: Prove $p → q \vdash ¬q → ¬p$ is valid.

The answer is:

> $1. p → q~~~~\textsf{premise}$
>
> $2. ¬q~~~~~\textsf{assumption}$
>
> $3. ¬p~~~~~\textsf{MT }1,2$
>
> $4. ¬q → ¬p~~~~~→\textsf{intro} 2,3$

Why isn't the assumption of $q$ included since $q$ or $¬q$ are both assumptions?

Comment: The assumptions of the proof are of two types: (i) what stay at the left of the "turnstile" $\vdash$ at the end of the proof: in your case the premise $p \to q$; and (ii) temporary assumptions that can be used and then "discharged" according to some rule of the calculus, like $\lnot q$ in your case, which has been discharged by $\to$-intro. In the above proof $q$ is **not** an assumption (and it is not needed).

Answer (score 1):

The reason we assume $\neg q$ is that we can then use it , the premise, and the *modus ponens* rule of inference to obtain a consequence, and on discharging the assumption we demonstrate that the premise entails the required conclusion.

$$\begin{align} & \begin{array}{l|l:l}
1  & p\to q & \textsf{premise}
\\ \hdashline 2 & \quad \neg q & \textsf{assume}
\\ 3 & \quad \neg p & \textsf{modus tollens } 1, 2
\\ \hline 4 & \neg q \to \neg p & \to\textsf{intoduction }2, 3  
\end{array} \\[0ex]\hline & p\to q ~\vdash ~\neg q\to \neg p\\ \Box
\end{align}$$

The reason we do not assume $q$ is that it is useless to.   There is no rule of inference which we can apply to it and the premise to give anything of interest.

$$\begin{align} & \begin{array}{l|l:l}
1  & p\to q & \textsf{premise}
\\ \hdashline 2 & \quad q & \textsf{assume}
\\ 3 & \quad  & (p\to q), q\textsf{ does not entail anything else} 
\\ \hline 4 & q \to q & \to\textsf{intoduction }2, 3  
\end{array} \\[0ex]\hline & p\to q ~\vdash q\to q\\ \require{cancel} \xcancel\Box
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question correctly but why should we add another assumption? We want to prove the above statement as is without extra assumptions.
On top, you might prove the other direction, then you assume q.

If you want to know *how* to prove it, the typical way is to write down all possibilities with a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and see the equivalence.

Comment: but what if assume q and conclude the contradiction? I mean why not consider both the case of q is true and q is false?

Comment: @ChenLu You can (!) prove both ways (/ using both assumptions), just write down the truth table and you'll see :)

Comment: ...But you don't have to, if your not asked for ^^